# Python: how to create a new file and write contents of variable to it?

Tags: python

I am writing a program that outputs the file types inside a directory by looking at their headers.

Some of the files are compressed so I need to be able to decompress them as a starting point

So far I have been able to search directories and using the header  change the extensions, and open the compressed file and store its contents in a variable, now I am having trouble saving the variable as a new file.

```
def unzip():
    os.chdir("C:/Users/David/Myfiles")
    files = os.listdir(".")
    for x in (files):
        f = open((x), "rb")
        byte1 = f.read(1)
        byte2 = f.read(1)
        if byte1 == b'\x1f' and byte2 == b'\x8b':
            os.rename((x), (x) + ".gz")
            file = gzip.open((x), "rb")
            content = file.read()   
            print (content)
```

I'm guessing I will have to use the a command along the lines of `f.write("newfile", content)` but not sure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you understand what ``f`` is here?

Comment: kind of why? not really an answer or anything is it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, if you have a string in a variable `foo`, you can write it to a file with:

```
with open('output.file','w') as f:
    f.write(foo)
```

In your case, you wouldn't use `f` as you're already using `f` for your *input* file handle.

I suppose you'd want something like:

```
def unzip():
    os.chdir("C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Cache")
    files = os.listdir(".")
    for x in (files):
        ifh = open((x), "rb")
        byte1 = ifh.read(1)
        byte2 = ifh.read(1)
        if byte1 == b'\x1f' and byte2 == b'\x8b':
            os.rename((x), (x) + ".gz")
            file = gzip.open((x), "rb")
            contents = file.read()   
            with open('output.file','w') as ofh:
                ofh.write(contents)
```

Comment: the default mode of a file object is read-only. you should open with 'w' or 'wb' (on windows) mode

Comment: ok thanks, what does the with statement do? cant i just write "ofh.open('output.file', '2' as ofh?

Comment: The `with` statement is called a [context-manager](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) that handles the closing of the file handle for you automagically.

Comment: so basically thats instead of typing ofh.close('filename')

Comment: Right.  In this case, `with` eliminates the need to explicitly close the file.

Answer (score 1):

you should do something like:

```
with open('filename.whatever', 'wb') as output:
    output.write(your_data)
```

check out the docs at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to look at the first two bytes to identify gz files. Instead, I think a more "Pythonic" approach would be to try first, apologize later (more commonly known as ["Easier to ask Forgiveness than Permission"](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)):

```
import os
import bz2
import gzip

def write(filename, content):
    with open(filename, 'w') as g:
        g.write(content)

def uncompress(dirpath):
    for filename in os.listdir(dirpath):
        filename = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        for opener in (gzip.open, bz2.BZ2File):
            try:
                with opener(filename) as f:
                    newfile, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
                    content = f.read()
                os.unlink(filename)
                write(newfile, content)
            except IOError:
                continue
            else: # break if try worked without IOError        
                break

dirpath = "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Cache"
uncompress(dirpath)
```

Also, it is better to avoid using `os.chdir` if possible because it alters the current directory even after you leave the `uncompress` function. If your script deals with other directories, then you have to carefully control what the current directory is at every stage of your program. If you use `os.path.join` instead, you never have to worry about what is the current directory.